# Black-list the [community] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

I think [community](/questions/tagged/community) is not on-topic on Stack Overflow (together with 90% of question tagged with it); it could be more appropriate for [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) SE, but not here.

What do you think about this?

Comment: At first glance, there isn't much there that'd be worth migrating to Programmers.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that this tag is more appropriate on programmes([community](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community)), not to migrate all low quality questions there. (sometimes I'm not good in translating my thoughts to English)

Comment: I voted the closed ones for deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at few questions using the tag, it seems it is a meta-tag, which doesn't add anything to the question.
I doubt there are users who follow that tag, also because it is used in completely unrelated questions.